# Error: no matching function for call to 'QLabel::text(QString&)'

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I try to make file browser but what is wrong

this is my *mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),
                                                 "",
                                                 tr("Files (*.mp3 *.ogg)"));
    ui->label->text(fileName);
}
```

errors:

```
C:\Users\account\eka\mainwindow.cpp:24: error: no matching function for call to 'QLabel::text(QString&)'
     ui->label->text(fileName);
                             ^
```

I just started with Qt, help me please.

Comment: if u are trying to set the filename to your label then use Ui->label->SetText(const QString &);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use setText() instead of text(). text() is a getter

`ui->label->setText(fileName);`